# React - Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of <Component /> from render

Tags: reactjs

Lets say I have component where I want function, which should return some generated "DOM" structure based on which I received in `filterTypesArray`. Then I want to render it using `{generateInputs}` in return function in my class. It throws me title warning. To avoid that, I have to implement this type of logic in `render` function as some `const`. I am new to react and I don't exactly get why it is so. I am not clever from that warning message.

Could someone explain me why it throws a warning message?

```
import * as React from "react";

interface IGridFilter {
    filterTypesArray: any[];
}

type GridFilterProps = IGridFilter;

export default class GridFilter extends React.PureComponent<GridFilterProps, {}>{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
    }

//here I want to do some logic and return some "DOM elements"
generateInputs = () => {
    return (
        <div> TEST </div>
    );
}
render() {
    //to avoid warning message I have to 
    //const generateInputs = this.props.filterTypesArray.map((input) =>
    //    <div>test</div>
    //);
    return (
        <div>
            {generateInputs}
        </div>
    );
}}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You didn't call `generateInputs`, hence you have a function reference in your render method, which React does not know how to render.

Try invoking the method:

```
return (
    <div>
        {generateInputs()}
    </div>
);
```

Comment: Ah yeah, it was my stupid mistake, thanks. Will accept when I can